# iOS 16: How to disable audible Siri (voice) feedback

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, siri

Before iOS 16, one could disable most of Siri’s audible feedback on the iPhone in *Settings > Siri & Search > Voice Feedback > Hands-Free Only*. [See the previous, more extensive settings here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/331199/45769).

In iOS 16, Siri is now audibly announcing the responses and feedback to everything I request.

**→ How does one achieve the above functionality again (ie. no voice feedback)?**

In other words, I only want to hear from Siri for Map-route directions, for example, and not for every little thing, for which I’m happy to read the feedback on the screen. I’ve checked under:

- *Settings > Siri & Search > Listen for “Hey Siri”* [already set to off]
- *Settings > Siri & Search > Siri Responses* [ticking “Automatic” doesn’t fix it]
- *Settings > Siri & Search > Announce Calls* [ticking “Headphones & Car” doesn’t fix it]
- *Settings > Siri & Search > Announce Notifications* [turning it off: doesn’t fix it]
- *Settings > Siri & Search > Announce Notifications* [“Headphones” to “on”: doesn’t fix it]
- *Settings > Accessibility > Siri > Spoken Responses* [ticking “Automatic”: doesn’t fix it]
- *Settings > Accessibility > Siri > Announce Notifications on Speaker* [turning it off: doesn’t fix it]

At this point, my only option seems to be to disable Siri completely (if that’s even possible). If I have to resort to this, how do I do it?

Comment: Oh, same thing. I never want to hear it. I feel it embarrassing for some reason.

Moreover, I speak quietly and use only shortcuts. Why on earth I have to hear her, if it’s not the headset.

Answer (score 2):

I found that if you ask Siri for something which requires a long answer (like “what is your favorite color “) while she is responding you can turn her volume all the way down to a whisper. She apparently has a separate volutes from the system setting. After that all Siri replies will be a whisper. Not a great solution but helps for now till Apple fixes this rather glaring problem.